# Can we use "now" with simple past tense as in "I saw it now"?

Tags: word-usage, past-tense

Can we use "now" with simple past tense? For example, Let's say someone is trying to show me something, but I can't see it. Right after seeing it, can I say, "Ok. I saw it now"?

Answer (score 4):

You could but it's not very formal. You might hear this in informal/regional usage or you could use it to establish a character's dialect, but it's not "good English".

If you have just seen it but you are no longer looking at it it would be better expressed as...

- I saw it just now
- I just saw it
- I've just seen it
- Now I've seen it

If something has just come in to view and you're still looking at it

- I see it now
- Now I see it
- I now see it (very formal)

But (and this is a stretch) if

- you were a time traveler trying to remember when you first saw something and you went back in time to the first time you saw the thing
- you were watching yourself on a CCTV recording of you seeing a thing

I guess you might say `Ok, I saw it now.`

Comment: Good answer you may want to incorporate some of Foogod's observation in the comments that explain *OK, I saw it now,* could be used when you have re-watched something several times in an attempt to see something you previously missed and you finally do see it -- a variation of, *I saw it this time.*

Comment: Even in the case EllieK describes I would say `OK, I see it now` or just `Ok, I saw it`. I think this use of `see` drifts in to a slightly different meaning of `to see` something, closer to saying `I understand now` or `i get it now`. `I watched the film once and I didn't see the foreshadowing, but I watched it again yesterday and I SEE IT NOW.`

Answer (score 0):

> Right after seeing it, can I say, "Ok. I saw it now"?

Yes, but keep in mind it would be a shortcut for saying "Ok. If someone were to ask you if I have seen it, you can now say yes".

If you are supposed to keep looking at this thing with the person showing it to you, rather than simply complete the task of seeing it, you should say "Ok. I see it now."

Comment: Lots of people would say: **I saw it just now**, meaning a few moments ago - although this may be part of my South African upbringing.

Comment: @LawrenceC Thank you. So you think it is okay if we use "now"with simple past tense, right?

Comment: I actually don't entirely agree with this.  If what you mean to say is "if someone were to ask you if I have seen it, you can now say yes", I think that would normally be expressed as "I *have seen* it now", not "I saw it now".  If what you mean is "I saw it, and the time I saw it was just a moment ago", then you could say "I saw it *just now*" (which is very standard, I think, not just a South African thing).

Comment: To me, "I saw it now" actually means "I saw it *this time*", that is, it would be used if there is something which has occurred several times, and you did not see when it happened previously, but you did see it on the most recent occurrence (which just happened).